# Машиностоительный завод — фабрика / завод-фабрика

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

> Машиностоительный завод — фабрика.

> Машиностоительный завод-фабрика.

Как я понимаю, по-розентальски надо писать с дефисом (http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111), а по-рановски — с тире (http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=80#pp80).

Comment: Методы Лысенко в терминологию? Если привить черенок фабрики к заводу, можно получить тот же завод. Среднего не получится, только с союзом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Машиностоительный завод-фабрика* — определяемое слово — *завод*, приложение — *фабрика*. Слово *машиностроительный* не является частью приложения или определяемого слова.

*Машиностоительный завод — фабрика* — определяемое словосочетание — *машиностроительный завод*, приложение — *фабрика*.

Если приложение или определяемое слово состоит из двух слов, ставим тире. Это несколько раз обсуждалось на сайте.

Comment: Максим, пожалуйста, к своем ответам давайте ссылки: Розенталь, грамматика и т.д. А то это похоже на мнение. Ну и семантику надо уточнить: что за завод-фабрика? Примеры желательны из литературы.

Comment: А где РАН и Розенталь? Вы не сравниваете варианты. Кто там прав?

Comment: Максим-с? Шерон права.

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр На этом сайте много раз эта тема обговаривалась. Можете в поисковик сайта ввести: «Приложение тире дефис». Поисковик по разным местам слова раскидывает, они не всегда вместе написаны. В общем, посмотрите, там написано, что тире нужно, если есть пробел в одной из частей.